# Вывод записей структуры по алфавиту

Tags: c++

**Задание:**

Описать структуру с именем STUDENT, содержащие поля:

- фамилия и инициалы;
- номер группы;
- успеваемость (массив из пяти элементов).

Написать программу, выполняющую следующие действия:

- ввод с клавиатуры данных в массив, состоящий из десяти структур типа STUDENT;
- вывод всех записей по алфавиту;
- вывод всех студентов, имеющих хотя бы одну оценку 2, если таких студентов нет, вывести соответствующее сообщение.

---

Сделал всё, кроме вывода записей по алфавиту (вроде как всё), вообще в голову не лезет, сказали сделать с помощью `strcmp()`, но додуматься не могу.

Код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

struct student 
{
    char* fio;
    int group;
    int usp[5];
};

int main()
{
    student data[10];
    int n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char temp[256];
        cout << "Введите ФИО студента №" << i << endl;
        cin >> temp;
        //cin.getline(temp, 256, '\n');
        data[i].fio = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
        strcpy(data[i].fio, temp);
        cout << "Введите номер группы студента №" << i << endl;
        cin >> data[i].group;
        cout << "Введите успеваемость студента №" << i << endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            cin >> data[i].usp[j];
    }

    cout << endl << "Записи, отсортированные по алфавиту:";
    /*
    Вывести отсортированную структуру
    */

    cout << endl << endl << "Студенты имеющие двойки: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            if(data[i].usp[j] == 2){
                cout << endl << "Фамилия: " << data[i].fio << endl;
                cout << "Номер группы: " << data[i].group << endl;
                cout << "Успеваемость: ";
                for(int g = 0; g < 5; g++)
                    cout << data[i].usp[g] << " ";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: отсортируйте студентов по фамилиям, сравнивая их через strcmp

Comment: Я и не могу додуматься как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы почему то стали инициализировать только  первые три элемента массива. Для начала четко укажите количество студентов:

```
constexpr int n = 10;
student data[n];
// ваш код где нужно инициализировать все элементы
```

существуют очень много альгоритмов для сортировки. Представлю один из них для сортировки ваших С_строк:

```
for (int k = n / 2; k > 0; k /=2)   
    for (int i = 0; i < n - k; ++i)             
        for (int j = i;  j >= 0; --j)           
            if (strcmp(data[j].fio, data[j + k].fio) > 0) {
                student temp = data[j];
                data[j] = data[j + k];
                data[j + k] = temp;
            }
```